# extracting value from IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo() swift

Tags: swift, iokit

I have this code:

```
var source =  IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo()
print(source)
```

When I run it, it returns this:

```
Optional(Swift.Unmanaged<Swift.AnyObject>(_value: <__NSCFArray 0x60800026f4c0>(
{
    "Battery Provides Time Remaining" = 1;
    BatteryHealth = Good;
    Current = "-1756";
    "Current Capacity" = 56;
    DesignCycleCount = 1000;
    "Hardware Serial Number" = C0143160D1JF90MAU;
    "Is Charging" = 0;
    "Is Present" = 1;
    "Max Capacity" = 100;
    Name = "InternalBattery-0";
    "Power Source ID" = 4063331;
    "Power Source State" = "Battery Power";
    "Time to Empty" = 117;
    "Time to Full Charge" = 0;
    "Transport Type" = Internal;
    Type = InternalBattery;
}
)
))
```

I am trying to get the "Is Charging" value from this closure. How would I do this?

I am new to Swift so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: source as Array, then first element as Dictionary, then element["Is Charging"] ?

Comment: @Larme could you expand on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/iokit/1523839-iopscopypowersourcesinfo?language=objc),

> Clients should not directly access data in the returned CFTypeRef - they should use the accessor functions IOPSCopyPowerSourcesList and IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription, instead.

Here is an example:

```
import IOKit.ps

let psInfo = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo().takeRetainedValue()
let psList = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesList(psInfo).takeRetainedValue() as [CFTypeRef]

for ps in psList {
    if let psDesc = IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription(psInfo, ps).takeUnretainedValue() as? [String: Any] {
        if let type = psDesc[kIOPSTypeKey] as? String,
            let isCharging = (psDesc[kIOPSIsChargingKey] as? Bool) {
            print(type, "is charging:", isCharging)
        }
    }
}
```

Output example:

```
InternalBattery is charging: false
```